# Getting '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object' while trying to reorder cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` to fetch `JSON` data in `UITableView` cells. I have declared the array as `NSMutableArray`, but still i'm getting `-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object` error and application is crashing whenever i'm trying to reorder the cells.

Here's the logic i'm using for reordering -

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
 toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

NSString *item = [self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking removeObject:item];
[self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];


}
```

I tried to look up the solutions which were being answered before, but couldn't understand. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: How are you initializing `jobsArrayFromAFNetworking` ?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *jobsArrayFromAFNetworking

Comment: That is the declaration... where do you _initialize_ the object?

Comment: I declared this in viewDidLoad method -     self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your @property `jobsArrayFromAFNetworking` is either initialized with an `NSArray` or declared `copy`.

Both would lead to this error message since the backing ivar would point to an (immutable) `NSArray`.

If you declared your property to be of `NSMutableArray` type, use `strong` as the storage modifier instead of `copy`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i'm using the property as @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayFromAFNetworking only. What could be the other issue?

Comment: Then the only explanation is that you accidentally assign a non-mutable `NSArray` to the property. Check all places where you assign to `jobsArrayFromAFNetworking`. To find all places I like to temporarily set the property to `readonly`. Then the compiler points you to all places where you assign a new array.

Comment: I'm assigning this array for a responseobject in AFNetworking
self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectForKey:@"all"];
Is there any problem with it?

Comment: Yes, that's usually just an immutable (plain) `NSArray`. You have to assign a mutable copy, instead: `self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"all"] mutableCopy];`